# ASP.NET WebAPI Identity 2 - Error with GetOwinContext on user registration /Register method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I have a WebAPI 2.1 application and I am having a problem with User Registration. I placed a breakpoint on the first line of the Register method but it is not reached. Instead it fails in the area below:

```
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            var a = Request; // this is null !!
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { // <<<<< Debug breakpoint here never reached
            Email = model.Email, 
            FirstName = model.FirstName, 
            LastName = model.LastName,
            OrganizationId = 1,
            OrganizationIds = "1",
            RoleId = (int)ERole.Student,
            SubjectId = 1,
            SubjectIds = "1",
            UserName = model.UserName
        };




System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: request
  Source=System.Web.Http.Owin
  ParamName=request
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Http.OwinHttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetOwinContext(HttpRequestMessage request)
       at WebRole.Controllers.AccountController.get_UserManager() in c:\G\abr\WebRole\Controllers\Web API - Data\AccountController.cs:line 50
       at WebRole.Controllers.AccountController.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in c:\G\ab\WebRole\Controllers\Web API - Data\AccountController.cs:line 376
       at System.Web.Http.ApiController.Dispose()
       at System.Web.Http.Cors.AttributeBasedPolicyProviderFactory.SelectAction(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRouteData routeData, HttpConfiguration config)
       at System.Web.Http.Cors.AttributeBasedPolicyProviderFactory.GetCorsPolicyProvider(HttpRequestMessage request)
  InnerException:
```

If anyone could give me any advice on where I could look to help solve this problem I would much appreciate it.

In particular can some explain to me the flow of how a request is handled in this configuration. I find it pretty confusing and I would like to know how the WebAPI and Owin fit together. Not knowing this is making it me difficult for me to understand the problem.

Thanks.

For reference here is my WebAPI start up class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

    }
}
```

Update 1 - question correct after Darin's comments. The problem is not in the constructor.

Update 2 - Dispose Method:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            UserManager.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Update 3 - Added the /Register method to show where I have a breakpoint (that's never reached)

Comment: Have you evaluated each part of that chain of operations?  I'm willing to bet one of them (probably the call to `GetOwinContext()` is null for some reason.  Tracking that down will most likely solve your issue

Comment: Please post your `AccountController.Dispose` method! the problem is that in the Dispose method you are not in the context of a web request, so the `Request` will be null and when you call `Request.GetOwinContext()` you get the exception...

Comment: @nemesv - It does not get to the dispose. My problem is in the constructor. I updated the question to show the value of the Request and it's null. Does that provide any more insight to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no check for a null _userManager in your dispose method but the backing field can still be null. Also you access the UserManager property instead of using the backing field directly. So every time _userManager is null and the AccountController gets disposed the UserManager will try to create a new OwinContext. And that will fail.

Change your dispose method to:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && _userManager != null)
    {
        _userManager.Dispose();
        _userManager = null
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: Onots - I am not sure this can be the problem as I am using the same sample code that's in the Identity Samples apps from Microsoft. I updated the question to show that the problem comes up before it even gets to the register method. It never hits my breakpoint at the start of the register method.

Comment: I didn't see the sample code, so I can't comment on that. But I'm fairly sure that in the Dispose method you shouldn't be constructing a new OwinContext.

Comment: Maybe there are multiple issues with the code. The stack trace you provided shows the exception originates from the dispose method. My answer should fix that. Maybe after fixing this any possible underlying issues will be more obvious.

Comment: I looked for some other samples and tried out the latest sample that comes up with VS2015. The dispose method is like yours and when I changed to yours then it solved that particular problem. Now I see another problem frustrating me. The /Register call returns a HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. I will look into that some more now.

Comment: Problems solved now as that was something else I added. I am still rather confused as to why all the samples and my old code used to work before. Anyway you pointed out the need for a change to Dispose and the very latest samples also have similar. Thanks for your help. Enjoy your New Year in Thailand if you are still there. I am also in Thailand.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I have is in the Account constructor

The HTTP Context is not available in a controller constructor and this is by design. The earliest point in the execution where you can access it is **after** the [`Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx) method:

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);

    // This is the earliest stage where you can access the HTTP context (request, response, ...).
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused as I believe what I am doing is similar to the WebAPI samples that all seem to use the same code for the constructor. For example: https://github.com/MikeWasson/LocalAccountsApp/blob/master/LocalAccountsApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs

Comment: In this example they are not accessing the Request property in the constructor. They are calling the setter of the `UserManager` property: `UserManager = userManager;`. From the exception you are describing it appears that you are calling the getter somewhere in the constructor as it is the getter that is trying to access Request. In any case you cannot access the HTTP context in a controller constructor simply because it is not available. So I'd double check whether there's some bit of code which is trying to do so and modify it.

Comment: You are correct and thank you for pointing that out. That puts me on the right path now but I still have a problem with the error message that is appearing.

Comment: Almost correct I think. It is the dispose method that tries to access the property if I understand it correct. Could you check if the AccountController.Dispose(bool disposing) uses the UserManager property or the _userManager backing field?

Comment: Yes, good point @Onots. Same stands true for the Dispose method in which the HTTP context might no longer exist.